# Django: How to differentiate ManyToMany relationship with the same model

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose `User` can block other `User`. Now I'm working on `ManyToManyField` that represents the list of blocked user. And the user can stop blocking other user as well. So I want to create a list of blocked user so the user can stop blocking.
However, the problem is if user A blocked user B, the blocked user list userB has has userA even though userA added userB to `ManyToManyField`. How can differentiate the relationship each user has in this case?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    block_users_list = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Comment: Take a look at [ManyToManyField.symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `symmetrical=False` for the relationship, and then try using the `related_name` attribute.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
      block_users_list = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='blocked_by_users')
```

now you have two ways of accessing the relationship:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
user.block_users_list.all() # Will return the list of users blocked by user
user.blocked_by_users.all() # Will return the list of users who have blocked the current user
```